# Speed of PubSub and gRPC PHP

Tags: php, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

We are experimenting with PubSub as a job queue and running our experiments from instances in the Google Cloud.

The problem we are currently facing is that making a connection and creating a job in PubSub takes around 300ms-700ms. We are running PHP, so on every incoming request, unfortunately, a new connection to PubSub needs to be made (at least for the front-end facing code). Is this an expected speed of the PubSub service, or are we maybe doing something wrong?

Another question is about gRPC for PubSub, this looks promising, but I can't seem to find any documentation or example code to start experimenting with this in a PHP environment. The only examples I found seem to work from AppEngine, which uses classes that are not available outside of AppEngine, as it seems.

I hope in both cases, I am missing something, I really would like to use PubSub.

**Update:** I partly solved the problem by setting a cache on the client. But it is still 200ms-500ms

Comment: When you say "making a connection," what do you mean? This is a publish call? A pull call? From what environment are you running your PHP code? Is this a GCE instance or a server hosted outside of Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: I meant the complete cycle of pushing a call, so making the https connection to the API and sending the data. We were testing it from local network, datacenter in Amsterdam and GCE (actually through the Container Engine) instance with PHP-FPM:5.6. We redid the test this friday and now everything seemed fine (< 70ms total time) from all sources, while a week ago, with exactly the same script, it was around 300-700ms. 
For now everything seems fine, but if things go south again in terms of speed, i'll put in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use PubSub + gRPC with the [Google Cloud PHP PubSub SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-pubsub) (`composer require google/cloud-pubsub`). See the [official documentation](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.32.1/pubsub/pubsubclient) for more info.

If you do use gRPC, be sure to also install the [protobuf extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/protobuf) rather than using the native PHP implementation. Without the extension, gRPC is actually **slower** than REST. To install the protobuf extension:

```
pecl install protobuf
```